# JQuery Autocomplete GET & JSON array data security concerns

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am learning JQuery with a MVC3 book. I find that Json data is really easy to use, but it may not be safe.

Consider the scenario, say, I got a CRM with senstive customer infomation. Ajax returns Json array as search results. The search textbox ajax autocomplete also return Json array of senstive keywords from database. etc...They all use GET method.

However, it is said that GET method has vulnerabilities when passing around Json array data:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx

How do you JQuery experts out there go about fixing this issue? Please help.

--- EDIT: ---

@Gren. Awesome. Thank you. Based on your tips, here is what I figured out.

1. The normal autocomplete returning json array
2. and a mod one with a json object wrapping the array

Here is the code, assuming we got a global List named txtlst in the controller.cs...

```
    // normal one
    public JsonResult AutoCompleteHelper1(string term) {
        //if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return null;
        var lst = txtlst.Where(s => s.StartsWith(term)).ToList();
        var res = lst.Select(x => new { value = x }).ToList();
        return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    //mod one
    public JsonResult AutoCompleteHelper2(string term) {
        //if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return null;
        var lst = txtlst.Where(s => s.StartsWith(term)).ToList();
        var res = lst.Select(x => new { value = x }).ToList();
        return Json(new { wrapper= res, name="wrapper" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

and then in the .cshtml file...

```
<p>Auto Complete Example</p>
<input type="text" name="q" id="MyInput1" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("AutoCompleteHelper1", "Home")"/>
<input type="text" name="q" id="MyInput2" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("AutoCompleteHelper2", "Home")" />
```

and then in the .js file...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // normal autocomplete
    $("#MyInput1").autocomplete({ source: $("#MyInput1").attr("data-autocomplete-source") });

    // mod autocomplete with a wrap
    $("#MyInput2").autocomplete({
        source: function (req, add) {
            $.getJSON($("#MyInput2").attr("data-autocomplete-source"), req, function (data) {
                var suggestions = [];
                $.each(data.wrapper, function (i, o) {
                    suggestions.push(o.value);
                });
                add(suggestions);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

--- EDIT 2: ---

> Please ignore those comments that are telling me to use POST.  They
>   are not reading the blog links or do not understand the issue.

Comment: Well, the first recommendation is instead of use GET, use POST

Comment: You can use a post request that sends a key of some sort to validate it... BTW, these examples are attacks on users, not attacks on your server; users are generally the weakest link when it comes to security

Comment: @Tom then use a different control. The method used for AJAX HTTP requests is your decision, ultimately. If some off-the-shelf tool doesn't do the right thing, then find another tool or implement your own.

Comment: Ah maybe you're talking about JSONP, not just JSON, right?  Well, the security model of JSONP is entirely different from that of ajax-based solutions. There's really no reason to use JSONP when you're working entirely within your own secured site however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other option is to wrap your JSON Arrays within JSON objects. The article and comments in it answered this question.

Edit:
From the article:

> The fact that this is a JSON array is important. It turns out that a script that contains a JSON array is a valid JavaScript script and can thus be executed. A script that just contains a JSON object is not a valid JavaScript file.

If you wrap your json array in an object {"myJsonArray":[{"name":"sensitive"},{"name":"data"}]} the HTML script tag would not be able to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Security of an Ajax/JSONP/JSON call is the same exact thing as the security of an http call since Ajax requests are http requests. Nothing changes in how you handle it. You make sure the user is logged in and can access the information.

If you are worried about data being cached, use Post or set the proper no caching headers with the backend.

EDIT:

- Things you can do to prevent JOSN from being read is the infinite loop trick. Stick an infinte  loop in front of the call, means your Ajax call will have to strip this before using it.
- You can use keys, third party site would not have the keys needed to validate the request.
- You can check referrers.

Comment: point is not Ajax. I can make a http call to get Json data. GET with Json data is what I am talking about here.

Comment: It does not matter it is an http call, just like your regular page loads are http calls. It is the same thing. All it is a webservice, same rules apply!

Comment: take jquery autocomplete for example, it doesn't have an option like method: POST. It is only doing GET. I need to open up a hole at server side MVC sayJsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, or the code won't work.

Comment: "All it is a webservice, same rules apply! " the blog from Phil Haack is talking about browser/client side security concerns. Not server.

Comment: Tom, is the webservice in the server or the client? The server. You still need to make sure that the user can access the data with verification that that is who they are and that there session can get the info.

Comment: Please read that blog. I am saying, a hacker's website can "borrow" the legitimate data from your client's browser cache. That means, your client has logged in, the hacker doesn't need to do it again. The hacker can read the Json data same as the logged in user. It is not a silly question, Gmail got hacked that way according to their info.

Comment: And you can do what a lot of sites do, they add the good old JavaScript infinite loop in front of the call. That way injecting it onto the page will cause the browser to lock up. Means you would have to hack jQuery UI to support and remove the loop.

Comment: Ah :D that's an interesting start! Thank you for the tips. Could you please show me a link or give me a bit more details to this approach? I want to check it out.